# Changing the background of a text at the pixel level

Tags: python, arrays, image, text, pixel

I want to change the change the background of a text, at the pixel level (using Python). However, I am struggling to figure which operation has to be performed to do so, given the RGB values of the background and the RGB values of each text pixel on a white background. For instance, in the image given example, how do the two pixels inside the red squares relate? (The image was obtained by screenshoting text on Microsoft Word)

Note that simply adding the two masks does not work (but gives a see through texture with non-black text)

PS: for the things I want to do, I cannot simply use PIL to do so.

[image: Two text instances compared: on white and yellow background]

Comment: can you use OpenCV? Also, what do you want to change the background to?

Comment: Can you post what you have right now so we can build upon it, rather than starting from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After performing a blend, you can bring back the blacks:

```
def change_background(img, color, recovery_color, intensity, recovery):
    mask = np.ones_like(img) * color
    blend = (1 - intensity) * img + intensity * mask

    # Bring back the important bits (e.g. black from img).
    # The closer the image is to the target color,
    # the stronger our recovery_mask.
    # You may need to tweak the formula.
    recovery_mask = 1 - (img - recovery_color)**recovery
    result = (1 - recovery_mask) * blend + recovery_mask * img

    return result
```

To use:

```
yellow = np.array([1.0, 1.0, 0.0])
black = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
img = change_background(
    img,
    color=yellow,
    recovery_color=black,
    intensity=0.2,
    recovery=0.5
)
```

---

**EDIT:** I thought about it a bit and another idea is just to use the B&W image as a blend mask directly:

```
def change_background(img, color, intensity):
    mask = np.ones_like(img) * color
    blend_mask = intensity * (1 - img[..., 0])
    blend = (1 - blend_mask) * img + blend_mask * mask
    return blend
```